# Long run stored procedure by windows service asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have five stored procedure,Each sp will take around more then one hour,am just running these sp using continuously by creating windows service,When run the service after one hour i got error related to connection

My connection string given below..i am using asp.net(C# coding)

Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User=xx;Password=xxxxx;

The error is A transport-level error has occurred during connection clean-up. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Comment: does it always drop after exactly one hour? Does it fail at a particular time?

Answer (score 0):

Transport level errors are often linked to the connection to sql server being broken ... usually network.

Timeout Expired is usually thrown when a sql query takes too long to run.

So few options can be :
1) check Internet connectivity (if connection between your sql server and visual studio is done through the net)
2) check for the connection in VPN (if used) or any other tool
3) restart IIS
4) Restart machine
5) Optimize sql queries.

Comment: i am just using windows service to run the stored procedure in same server,Can u please guide me

Comment: In the object of web service, you can edit and increase the time out. There is a property like obj.settimeout (don't remember exact property value). You can start from here